# Delete all rows except 100 most recent ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-delete

I am using MS SQL Server and I have a table named `Logs` that looks like this:

[image: table logs(dateTime, errorDescription)]

Records are added frequently so the table becomes quite big after few days/weeks.

I need to perform a little cleanup periodically: I need query that would delete older rows and keep only the most recent 100 rows in the table.

I understand it would have been better to have it *delete records older than some date*... but I am asked to do it as described above.

Comment: what do you need to do?  delete old records or delete all records except the most recent 100?  what happens if you get 101 records in a single second? does that mean you will then miss out on the first record?

Comment: Is there an ID or anything that makes row unique?

Comment: disc space is so cheap these days I would argue with rows of that size, nothing would ever need to be deleted.  If you ever ***did*** need to delete, I would not delete based on "leave this many records remaining", but rather "delete records older than x date."

Comment: @Kritner : I don't understand your questions, but all I can say is: Usually there's a cleanup job that occurs somewhere at 3:00am, normally no new records arrive at that hour... And, yes I agree records should be deleted based on date rather than number :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

```
-- offset clause
WITH goners AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Logs
    ORDER BY DateTime DESC
    OFFSET 100 ROWS 
)
DELETE FROM goners

-- numbered rows
WITH goners AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS rn, Logs.*
    FROM Logs
)
DELETE FROM goners
WHERE rn > 100

-- nth value
-- note that this "keeps" all rows that tie for last place
DELETE FROM Logs
WHERE DateTime < (
    SELECT MIN(DateTime)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 100 DateTime
        FROM Logs
        ORDER BY DateTime DESC
    ) AS x
)
```

Comment: Couldn't the latter work with the [DateTime] column as is too?

Comment: @SalmanA : What if there are more records with DateTime = MIN(DateTime) ...? I guess it is possible to have less than 100 rows after executing your query (the first one I'm talking about). Right?

Comment: @groenhen: yes, the first approach does not guarantee that exactly 100 records will be kept. It is possible to have **more** than 100 rows (since we are using `<`) when e.g. row #100, 101 and 102 have same datetime.

Comment: @groenhen see revised answer

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with others that this is probably not the way to go, here's a way to do it anyway:

```
;WITH keepers AS
(   SELECT TOP 100 [DateTime]
    FROM dbo.Logs
    ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC )
DELETE FROM dbo.Logs a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM keepers b WHERE b.[DateTime] = a.[DateTime] )
```

Comment: It doesn't work :  it says "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'."

Comment: Ok, it works after some minor corrections, yet I keep counting 101 records each time I execute the query...

Comment: Any duplicate [DateTime] values?

Comment: Hmmm, possible! Now it;s too late to check... I have run lots of queries on that table... it's messed up, but I suppose you're possibly right :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `NOT EXISTS`, just use `>=`:

```
WITH keepers AS (
    SELECT TOP 100 [DateTime]
    FROM dbo.Logs
    ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
   )
DELETE FROM dbo.Logs a
    WHERE l.DateTime < (SELECT MIN([DateTime]) FROM keepers);
```

I'm not sure if there are lock settings where new rows could be added in while the `delete` is running.  If so, this would still be safe for that.

You can actually simplify this in SQL Server 2012+:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Logs a
    WHERE l.DateTime < (SELECT [DateTime] 
                        FROM dbo.logs
                        ORDER BY [DateTime]
                        OFFSET 99 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
                       );
```

Comment: Ok, it works after some minor corrections (missing parenthesis, etc.)

Comment: Would this work when the amount of data is about 40GB, I inherited a huge data where maximum is a single log table  never cleaned for 2yr. Now have to clean this and save only a month data, moving rest to archive (via another copy)

Comment: @NitinSingh . . . Yes.  You would want indexes to speed the queries and if many rows are being deleted, you might want to take a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @cutoff DATETIME
SELECT TOP 100 @cutoff = [DateTime] FROM Logs ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
DELETE FROM Logs WHERE [DateTime] < @cutoff
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
;with cte as(select top(select count(*) - 100 from table) * from table order by dt)
delete from cte
```

Comment: Yet I think it wont work if at some moment count(*) is less than 100, i.e. selecting a NEGATIVE number of rows/records...