# delete some old records from postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as:

```
table t1
id int
room text
record_date timestamp
```

How can I delete some records in t1 table, except the newest 100 records of a room(record_date is used to save the timestamp to compare with)?

With mysql I did the next and it works:

```
DELETE  p FROM t1 p
            LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT id,room
            FROM t1
            ORDER BY record_date DESC
            LIMIT 101) p2 on p2.id=p.id and p2.room=p.room 
            WHERE p2.id IS NULL and p.room='myroom'
```

But postgres doesn´t works with it and results on error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
DELETE FROM t1
WHERE (room, id) NOT IN (
    SELECT room, id
    FROM t1
    WHERE room = 'myroom'
    ORDER BY record_date DESC
    LIMIT 100
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253628/delete-all-rows-except-100-most-recent-ones):

```
WITH todelete AS (
   SELECT * FROM t1
   WHERE room = 'myroom'
   ORDER BY record_date DESC
   OFFSET 100 ROWS
 )
 DELETE FROM todelete;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following command:

```
DELETE FROM t1
WHERE room = 'myroom' AND NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT id
   FROM t1 p2
   WHERE p2.room = t1.room
   ORDER BY record_date DESC
   OFFSET 100
   LIMIT 1
);
```

The reason of using 'NOT EXISTS' will ensure that selected records are older than  the 100th newest record in the room.